# Which functions produce the "would like to access your contacts" window in MacOS 10.8?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I don't use the ABAddressBook framework at all. I have no clues why my application want to access the contacts? There are no exceptions, or useful log data...

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries (for advertisement, usage tracking etc.)?

Comment: We use many frameworks, but none of them should use ABAddressBook... Is there an official way to "catch" why this privacy window is displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any documentation I know of. I would try to set a breakpoint in the debugger on `+addressBook` and `+sharedAddressBook` of the `ABAddressBook` class and the relevant C functions such as `ABGetMe` and `ABGetSharedAddressBook`.

Furthermore, stop the app in the debugger as soon as the dialog appears and investigate all threads for suspicious function calls because OS X will be blocking the the call until the user has click one of the options.

In a related post in the Apple Developer Forums, I've read that the InstantMessage framework for iChat Theater support was the culprit in that case.

Comment: Thanks! InstantMessage.framework was the culprit: the function [IMAVManager sharedAVManager] will produce the "would like to access your contacts" window.

Comment: Depending on where you call the function [IMAVManager sharedAVManager] for the first time, the "would like to access your contacts" window can crash your application... Thanks Apple for this new great feature!